# pubsub <-> bigquery with protobuf: bool is getting converted to null or true, not false or true

Tags: google-bigquery, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a protobuf pubsub schema being published to bigquery (directly, no dataflow).

in the protobuf, i have a field like:

`bool foo = 1;`

In the bigquery schema this becomes:

```
  "name": "foo",
  "type": "BOOLEAN",
  "mode": "NULLABLE"
 },
```

From my python code, I call publish on the topic w/ a dict (encoded to bytes) that has:

`foo: false`

this becomes `foo: null` in the output bigquery table.

if I make if

`foo: true`

it becomes `foo: true` in the bigquery table.

this is happening for all of my bool. e.g. false becomes null, true remains true.

Suggestion on where to look?

Comment: Are you using proto2 or proto3?

Comment: this is using proto3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug with proto3 support that is being actively worked on. You can track progress in the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/251885844). For now, the workaround is to use proto2 instead of proto3.

Answer (score 0):

The [JSON Mapping](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json) section from the Protocol Buffer documentation says:

> . . . *If a field has the [default value](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#default) in the protocol buffer, it will be omitted in the JSON-encoded data by default to save space.*

As `false` is the default value for protocol Buffer's `bools`, the above seems to suggest that `foo: false` by default became `foo: null` to save space.

I reckon this is a bug because [float value 0.0 is also being converted to null in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74723783/bigquery-saves-float-value-0-0-and-boolean-false-as-null).