# BigQuery saves Float value 0.0 and Boolean false as null

Tags: python, types, google-bigquery, protocol-buffers, jsonschema

I am using a cloud function (python 3.10 runtime) to receive and encode the below JSON payload within a protobuf schema, and publishing to a PubSub topic that allows the data to be processed to BigQuery.

###### payload

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "user_id": "XY25999A",
      "firstname": "John",
      "lastname": "Doe",
      "fee": 20.00,
      "is_active": false
    },
    {
      "user_id": "XY26999B",
      "firstname": "Sam",
      "lastname": "Foo",
      "fee": 0.00,
      "is_active": true
    },
    {
      "user_id": "XY27999C",
      "firstname": "Kay",
      "lastname": "Bent",
      "fee": 20.00,
      "is_active": true
    }
  ]
}
```

###### json schema

```json
{
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{
       "user_id":{
          "type":"string"
       },
       "firstname":{
          "type":"string"
       },
       "lastname":{
          "type":"string"
       },
       "fee":{
          "type":"number"
       },
       "is_active":{
          "type":"boolean"
       }
    }
 }
```

###### protobuf schema

```protobuf
message ProtoSchema {
    string user_id = 1;
    string firstname = 2;
    string lastname = 3;
    double fee = 4;
    bool is_active = 5;
  }
```

When the data is processed to BigQuery, **is_active** for *John* and **fee** for *Sam* are both showing `null` instead of `false` and `0.0` respectively.

| user_id | firstname | lastname | fee | is_active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XY25999A | John | Doe | 20.00 | null |
| XY26999B | Sam | Foo | null | true |
| XY27999C | Kay | Bent | 20.00 | true |

Is there a reason or explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Hmmm there's an IssueTracker [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/251885844) that appears to reflect your experience but which is marked as fixed. Perhaps a regression?

Answer (score 0):

All fields in proto3 messages are implicitly `optional` unless `required` is explicitly set. It helps to save encoded message sizes. I guess the cloud function documents that default bool and double values of missing fields are `false` and `0` respectively and the fields are not set if they have default values. So, the data precessor should use default values for the missing fields.

Comment: I'm using proto3 and `required` is discouraged. In fact there's no option to use required in proto3: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview#syntax

Comment: Ok, I forgot it and supposed it was still usable.